# Having trouble listing down state map or prop map in React

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reactjs, redux

Here is whats inside my `tbody` tag:

```
{this.props.listingData.map((listingData,index) => 
                                <tr key={index}>
                                    <td>{listingData.location_id}</td>
                                    <td>{listingData.location}</td>
                                    <td>{listingData.description}</td>
                                </tr>
                            )}
```

I'm getting `map of undefined` error.

Tried logging `this.props.listingData` & it works.

Here is sample `map` data which I used:

```
[{"location_id":1,"location":"HKG","description":"Hong Kong","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":2,"location":"KUL","description":"Kuala Lumpur","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0}]
```

Should be working?

My `getDefaultProps`:

```
getDefaultProps() {
        return {
          //value: 'default value' //called as this.props.value
          listingData: [{"location_id":1,"location":"HKG","description":"Hong Kong","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0},{"location_id":2,"location":"KUL","description":"Kuala Lumpur","update_by":null,"update_time":null,"create_by":null,"create_time":null,"rec_state":0}]
        };
    }
```

Tried this and still getting the error.

Comment: At what point is `this.props.listingData` assigned? Are you sure that the component isn't rendered before it has a value?

Comment: When the app starts, I get a list of data and assign it. I tried `componentWillMount()` works & `componentDidMount()` also works but I get the `map of undefined` error.

Comment: Be more defensive: `{this.props.listingData && this.props.listingData.map(...`

Comment: Do you load asyncly the listingData? if it's the case you have to specify a default props for listingData as an empty array

Comment: see the details here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values

Comment: @MichaelRasoahaingo yes its async loading that why I'm getting the error. I tried your suggestion using `getDefaultProps()` but I'm still having a problem. Can you give an example working code?

Comment: Show us a minimal component with `render` and `getDefaultProps`.

Comment: My component only have this `render` which is a table with the body I provided above. I've added `getDefaultProps` in my post, both still getting the error unless I hard code `this.props.listingData` with sample data then it works fine. The code above is what I used.

Comment: The reason I said to do that is there are numerous ways you can define a component (a stateless function, using `React.createClass`, a `class`, ...). The best way to assign some default props depends on which method you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the default props that is a good practice when creating you component, according to the document https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#default-prop-values:

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({

  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      listingData: []
    };
  },

  render: function () {
    //...
  }

});
```

or es2015

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    //...
  }

}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  listingData: []
}
```

with static property support

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    listingData: []
  };

  render() {
    //...
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm using ES6 btw, and I did exactly what you did & added sample data. Still getting the same error. I've edited my post with my code. Can you check it?

Comment: But if you are using redux, you can add defaults data as initialState also, it depend of what you want to handle inside the store

Comment: I am in fact using redux, which method is better? If you don't mind can you also show an example using initialState? Thanks a bunch

Comment: Component and store are 2 different parts of building an app. When you write a component default props is part of your component description that tell about his default behavior. With redux, as your data store, it can have default state (initial state). Good practice is defining default props to your component, without knowing the store.

Comment: @Joshua Good practice is simply to make your component resilient to whatever props are passed to it (or not). Whether you achieve this using default props or by coding more defensively depends on your use case. Be aware that setting very specific default props can reduce the reusability of your component.

Comment: Alright,I'll take note of what both you said, thanks for your time & help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're performing an asynchronous fetch and passing the response as a prop to this component. This means that the first time the component is rendered, it will be undefined (try putting a breakpoint inside `render` and see for yourself).

As you've seen, you can't call `map` on `undefined`, so you need to return something else if you don't have the data yet. Personally I prefer something along these lines:

```
if (!this.props.listingData) return null;

return this.props.listingData.map(listingData => // ...
```

There are clearly other ways you can write this. Alternatively, you can provide default props.

Note if `location.id` is unique, you should use that as your `key`, rather than the loop index.

Comment: Can you show an example when using `default props`? I tried using it but I think I might be doing it wrongly. Thanks. Btw I'm using ES6

Comment: If you are explicitly passing `undefined` as a prop before you get the response, then I don't think that default props will work.